# Is this a steal or a block and rebound?

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

This was recorded as a steal. I'm wondering how this can be justified. It looks like McDaniels tries to tip it in. If that's the case, then how can it be ruled a steal? Here is the [clip](https://www.nba.com/stats/events?CFID=&CFPARAMS=&ContextMeasure=STL&EndPeriod=0&EndRange=28800&GameID=0022200828&PlayerID=1631117&RangeType=0&Season=2022-23&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&StartPeriod=0&StartRange=0&TeamID=1610612762&flag=1&sct=plot&section=game).

Comment: While McDaniels certainly touched the ball, it's not clear that he actually caused it to move *up* towards the basket, which I think is required for this to be considered a shot.

Comment: He clearly causes it to move towards the basket. The ball was arcing downwards and then moves upwards after he makes contact.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask the scorekeeper to be sure; however, I suspect the direct answer is that the ball never cleared the rim after the touch, so they decided he did not successfully get a shot off.  He probably intended to try and shoot it, but when the positioning and timing didn't work out, it became a bad pass instead of a shot that was rebounded.

Comment: I don't see how that could be interpreted as a pass rather than a shot. Who is he passing to?

Comment: The pass was in to McDaniels (which is *clearly* a pass, that's something they practice extensively).

Comment: To be clear, the pass wasn't really all that bad - the timing/power of McDaniels' jump was the issue.  However, the turnover tends to be credited to the passer in these circumstances even so (imagine the extreme example of a lob from the opposite baseline to half court where the other player is supposed to run to a spot, and instead runs towards the baseline, so nobody is home - that's the fault of the runner, not the thrower, but it's considered a bad pass anyway.)

Comment: I thought you were implying that McDaniels was attempting to pass rather than shoot.

Why does the ball have to clear the rim for it to be a shot attempt? The player just has to be attempting to score, right?

Comment: It's all judgement, but that's a reasonable way to see it - he clearly didn't actually "shoot" per se (there's no proper shooting motion), so the difference between a failed tip in and a failed reception of a pass is a matter of judgement.  Here, I suggest that since the ball didn't clear the rim (nor particularly go towards the basket), he didn't actually shoot - just hit the ball.

Comment: I can see why one would think it's a judgement call but I think that given that he moves the ball towards the basket, it's clearly an attempt to score the basket. The fact that it didn't clear the rim should be irrelevant. But even so, the ball definitely moves towards the basket from McDaniels contact when you watch frame by frame.

Comment: All I can say is the official scorer said otherwise, and I’d say they’re a better judge of this than you or me.

Comment: Well they probably made the decision in real-time, not having the benefit of replay.